# How to run cakephp 3 project placed inside the cakephp 3 project webroot

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I would like to run the cakephp3 project placed inside the cakephp3 project webroot

```
/example.com/
  bin/
  config/
  logs/
  plugins/
  src/
  tests/
  tmp/
  vendor/
  webroot/ 
     /uat/ (this is another project placed inside webroot)
       bin/
       config/
       logs/
       plugins/
       src/
       tests/
       tmp/
       vendor/
       webroot/ 
       ...
       ...
       ...
  .gitignore
  .htaccess
  .travis.yml
  composer.json
  index.php
  phpunit.xml.dist
  README.md
```

I'm trying to access another project using the address `https://example.com/uat/index.php`, but it throws the error:-

**Uat class not found**

```
2018-08-07 12:54:53 Error: [Cake\Routing\Exception\MissingControllerException] Controller class Uat could not be found.
Request URL: /uat/index.php
Stack Trace:
#0 /home/corpveda/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/ControllerFactory.php(72): Cake\Http\ControllerFactory->missingController(Object(Cake\Network\Request))
#1 /home/corpveda/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/ActionDispatcher.php(93): Cake\Http\ControllerFactory->create(Object(Cake\Network\Request), Object(Cake\Network\Response))
#2 /home/corpveda/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/BaseApplication.php(83): Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Cake\Network\Request), Object(Cake\Network\Response))
#3 /home/corpveda/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(65): Cake\Http\BaseApplication->__invoke(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#4 /home/corpveda/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Middleware/RoutingMiddleware.php(62): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response))
#5 /home/corpveda/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(65): Cake\Routing\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#6 /home/corpveda/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Middleware/AssetMiddleware.php(93): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response))
#7 /home/corpveda/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(65): Cake\Routing\Middleware\AssetMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#8 /home/corpveda/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Middleware/ErrorHandlerMiddleware.php(81): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response))
#9 /home/corpveda/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(65): Cake\Error\Middleware\ErrorHandlerMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#10 /home/corpveda/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php(51): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response))
#11 /home/corpveda/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Server.php(92): Cake\Http\Runner->run(Object(Cake\Http\MiddlewareQueue), Object(Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest), Object(Zend\Diactoros\Response))
#12 /home/corpveda/public_html/webroot/index.php(37): Cake\Http\Server->run()
#13 {main}
```

This was required to set up the UAT server for our team, I have also tried some example from google by modifying the **.htaccess** file found inside the webroot folder to make it work, but it throws the same error each time.

Comment: try another projects as plugin

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible, but as @Salines said you can probably work something for your needs by creating one or more plugins, as they are basically self contained mini applications within your main app. [Creating Your Own Plugins](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#creating-your-own-plugins)

Comment: Thnaks #Salines & #BadHorsie for your suggestion, I will try these step and test if it's works.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your best option : https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html